# Menu inside fragment not getting called

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d("Does", "get called");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitem, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Below is my onCreateView method, where i am calling

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
          setHasOptionsMenu(true);
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
}
```

I don't get the log statements or the menu getting called in my action-bar.

**Update**: I tried calling this from onCreate method of fragment, yet the menu is not shown.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);        
}
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/section" android:title="@string/section"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_section"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/refresh" android:title="@string/refresh" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/edit_patient" android:title="@string/edit_patient" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_editpatient"
        android:showAsAction="always" />    

    <item android:id="@+id/about" android:title="@string/about"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/help" android:title="@string/help"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/signout" android:title="@string/signout"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: which version of android you are using i mean the api level..

Comment: @Abhijit <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: Please also add your R.menu.menuitem xml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to make a call of [`setHasOptionsMenu(true);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29) from within one of the starting lifecycle methods of the Fragment. Preferably from within `onCreate(...)`.

In a minimalistic case the `onCreate` method of your Fragment looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Also, calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);` after you have inflated your custom menu will reset the menu you just have inflated to an empty menu.

So either call:

```
@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d("Does", "get called");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitem, menu);
}
```

or:

```
@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d("Does", "get called");
    //no super call
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitem, menu);
}
```

Also, if you're testing on a Gingerbread device, the menu might not be displayed if the hosting `Activity` does not contain a menu item of it's own.

Comment: When i try to call setHasOptionsMenu(true) from my activity onCreate() method, i get this error. " The method setHasOptionsMenu(boolean) is undefined for the type BaseActivity "

Comment: You'll need to call this method from within the Fragment, as stated above.

Comment: I am testing it on Google Nexus tablet, so in that case what should i do.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer , if you're testing on a Gingerbread device, the menu might not be displayed if the hosting Activity does not contain a menu item of it's own. Can you please explain a bit more as i am having the same issue.(i think)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420023/action-bar-sherlock-searchview-not-expanding-on-click-of-it

Comment: Just adding my 2cents here. This post helped me to get through my matter, but was not enough. Being said I have been following latests Google docs (Material Design, and AppCompat v21) using Toolbar, I initially added my Toolbar in the "standalone" way (you can check it here http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html ). This meant that my Toolbar was not attached and used as an ActionBar. Thus, the post content was not helping me here. As I changed the way to handle the Toolbar (now using setSupportActionBar() ), everything ran smoothly.