# onCreateOptionsMenu not getting called inside the Fragment class

Tags: java, android

```
public class FragmentClass extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    }   

    @Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        Log.d("Does", "get called");
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuItem, menu);
    }
```

}

`onCreateOptionsMenu` method is never called even though i have placed `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside my `onCreate` Method.

This is how my `Activity class` looks like.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/FragmentChangeActivity.java

More update: This is my method inside `Fragment Class`.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.facesheet, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

This is inside the BaseActivity class.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Menu inside fragment not getting called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654793/menu-inside-fragment-not-getting-called)

Comment: @keyboardsurfer: well it did not work...

Comment: Are there errors or warnings showing ?

Comment: @Zakaria: no there is no errors or warnings... the fragments gets called and layout is loaded... the menu does not show up.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer: i will keep a note of it... i thought it got solved... but it did not really.

Comment: @Kevin what about your activity ? does it extend the FragmentActivity from the support library ? No SherlockActionBar involved ?

Comment: It extends the BaseActivity " public class FacesheetMainActivity extends BaseActivity {" of the Sliding Menu

Comment: @Zakaria:  have updated the class file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not overriding the right method.

Try this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuItem, menu);
    return true;
}
```

[Source link.](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/BaseActivity.java)

Comment: The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type FragmentClass must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: You are extending the `BaseActivity` class. Please, take a look at its content : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/BaseActivity.java

Comment: Getting, i removed those two methods from BaseActivity Class.... i get this error when i add them "The method inflate(int, Menu) in the type MenuInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, Menu)"

Comment: @Kevin this is because your kept the "boolean" as the returned type. Try with "void" instead.

Comment: Can u check my updated post... where i have updated both the methods and check if its correct.

Comment: @Kevin I'm justing helping. It's up to you to tell us if the solution works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27070/discussion-between-kevin-and-zakaria)

Answer (score 0):

Additional try to call `setMenuVisibility(true);`