# Action Bar Sherlock SearchView not expanding on click of it

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, searchview

I have one Sherlock Fragment Activity from which i am setting the different sherlock fragments using fragment pager adapter.

Now to show the searchview in each of the fragment i have placed this method in onCreate of Fragment::

This method will show menu items in the ActionBar of the fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

I have now also set the onCreateOptionMenu() like this ::

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
}
```

Now the strange things happens that in my first fragment i have done the same thing and the searchview get opened successfully.

If

- i go to the first fragment,open the searchview  then go to the second
- fragment the searchview will get opened.

Same thing happens for third fragment

- go to 3rd fragment,
- open searchview,
- back to the second frgment,searchview get opened.

But if i go to directly on the second fragment the searchview not get opened.

Hope i am clear.

Any clue about this?
Any suggestion/links will be appreciated..

Thanks in Advance...

**EDIT ::**

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" 
        android:title="Search Products">
    </item> 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_Home"
                android:icon="@drawable/home"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Home"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
                android:icon="@drawable/favourite"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Favourite"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_Balance"
                android:icon="@drawable/balance"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Balance"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/btn_logout"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

**Logcat ::**

```
    12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mobifin.subscriber.ButtonPayActivity
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.mobifin.subscriber.home.BillPayFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(BillPayFragment.java:101)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:55)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:466)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:265)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:149)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:155)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(Fragment.java:726)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:127)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:802)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1280)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1176)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1562)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-06 16:45:26.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you paste your menu.xml file? That might help to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what i want finally but with one problem..
I don't know whatever i have done is the hack/patch or the correct way but it is working fine in <3.0 but now find the issue in >=3.0.

What i have done is ::

In My Container Activity i have declare the onCreateOptionsMenu() and onPrepareOptionsMenu() ::

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        if(versionStatus==0)
        {
            menu.findItem(R.id.root_menu).setVisible(false);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Now in each Fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu() i have done something like this :: 
I have checked the build version of OS and based on that i manupulate my option menu like below ..

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        int versionStatus = 0;
        if (currentapiVersion == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO || currentapiVersion == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        {
            versionStatus=0;
        }
        else if(currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            versionStatus=1;
        }
        if(versionStatus==1)
        {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).setVisible(false);

            final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
            searchView.setQueryHint("Search Products");
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        }
        else
        {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
            searchView.setQueryHint("Search Products");
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        }
    }
```

It's working fine in 2.3.3 but problem m facing now is in 3.0 +

1)not able to see the hint after expanding the searchview
2)expand the searchview in first fragment...
[image]

3)Move to second fragment(without collapsing the searchview )
[image]

4)Now in second fragment expand the searchview of current fragment 
[image]

5)in Current Fragment Pressed Back then the result is mess :(

[image]

**EDIT ::**

I have done the following changes in my Container Activity and now its working fine,Finally i have achieved what i want....

```
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            if(versionStatus==0)
            {
                getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        {
            if(versionStatus==0)
            {
                menu.findItem(R.id.root_menu).setVisible(false);
            }
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

We generally use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for creating Options Menu for fragments and activities. 
If you go through the documentation, there's another helper method called `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` which, as per the documentation says:

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.

`SearchView` expanding/collapsing works fine when we are not instantiating fragments inside `ViewPager` or anything similar tab like switching scenarios. I've had the same problem once.
I came up with using `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to resolve my problem.

Just implement `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in each of your fragments and inside of it, call `onQueryTextChange("")` passing `""` as query string. It will do the trick to suggest the fragment container activity that this fragment wants to mind his own searching business.

OR , Not sure, but a call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on container activity could also come handy.

Let me know if that helps.

**EDIT:**

My Implementation:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search for Events");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        menu.add(0, ACTION_SEARCH, 0, "Search")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mailbox_search)
                .setActionView(searchView)
                .setOnActionExpandListener(menuExpandListener)
                .setShowAsAction(
                        MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    }

@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        onQueryTextChange("");
    }

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        if (mAdapter != null)
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: so you are trying to say that i should remove my onCreateOptionMenu() code to onPrepareOptionMenu() ? correct me if i am getting you wrong...

Comment: No. Keep onCreateOptionsMenu() there adding onQueryTextChangeListener to searchView and add onPrepareOptionsMenu(). See my edit.

Comment: i have make changes as you said but my app gets crashed.I have pasted the code in my edit and also mentioned the line where my app gets crashed... please look into this..

Comment: The fragment needs to implement the OnQueryTextListener. After implementing that pass 'this' as parameter; eg. searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

Comment: i have implemented the onQueryTextListener() in fragment.but the result will be same.I am getting the context in the context in the constructor of the fragment.so m using `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((OnQueryTextListener) ctx);`  to use the onQueryTextListener...See my edit...

Comment: which searchView are you importing? check if this is what you are importing:                                                        import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;

Comment: `import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;` m using action bar sherlock imports...

Comment: Remove my answer from the question and replace it with the crash log you are seeing in the logcat. I couldn't think about something else..

Comment: i have made the changes as per you said,i get the success,but i got stuck here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520692/weired-behaviour-of-supportinvalidateoptionsmenu-in-action-bar-sherlock-fragment can you plz help me on this??

Comment: i have implemented the logic as you suggested above to implement the `onPrepareOptionMenu()` in each fragment,after that i have added `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in container activity,then my first tab fragment searchview not expand but works 2nd and 3rd and if i add `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in container activity then first tab fragment not working,but 2nd and 3rd works ... why this happening any idea ?