# Sherlock ActionBar SearchView not working in multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am in great need of you as i am stuck in this issue from the last 4 days.

So,here is the thing....

I have one sherlock fragment activity from which i calling the six fragments inside viewpager.

Now i want to manipulate the sherlock action bar depends on the selected tab.

So for the first 3 tab i want to show the searchview and overflow menu icon.

For that what i have tried so far ::

I am in great need of you as i am stuck in this issue from the last 4 days.

So,here is the thing....

I have one sherlock fragment activity from which i calling the six fragments inside viewpager.

Now i want to manipulate the sherlock action bar depends on the selected tab.

So for the first 3 tab i want to show the searchview and overflow menu icon.

For that what i have tried so far ::

1) Called the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in every fragment.
2) Added the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in every fragment. and

then i have achieved what i want.

Now i want that onClick of the searchview it should get expanded and collapse when pressed the back. So to achieve that i have added this in my first 3 fragment and also implement the [puru's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420023/action-bar-sherlock-searchview-not-expanding-on-click-of-it) logic .(Create the `onPrepareOptionMenu()` in every fragment and add the `onQueryTextChange("");` method).

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

**Fragment Code ::**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search for Products");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
       }



@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        onQueryTextChange("");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" 
        android:title="Search Products">
    </item> 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_Home"
                android:icon="@drawable/home"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Home"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
                android:icon="@drawable/favourite"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Favourite"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_Balance"
                android:icon="@drawable/balance"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Balance"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/btn_logout"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**Problem :: (on Pre-HoneyComb Device)**

Now when i click of the first fragment's searchview,it not get expanded,but works well for fragment 2 and fragment 3.

Steps ::

1)go to directly fragment 1,click on searchview,not expanding
2)go to directly on fragment 2 tab(not clicking onsearchview in second fragment),back to fragment 1,searchview expanding
3)go to directly on fragment 3 tab(not clicking onsearchview in third fragment),back to fragment 1,searchview expanding

Is there any issue related to the focus of searchview? or am i calling the `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` in some unusual way?

Let me know if you need anything more from my side...
Please guide me in my implementation... Any clue why this strange behaviour happens? Any suggestion/explnation will be appreciated....

Plz plz help me on this issue....
Thanks in Advance...